# Http Post image fails in browser/Ripple emulator

Tags: javascript, cordova, http, post, xmlhttprequest

I am writing a small Cordova (PhoneGap) app. that is sending an image from a file input - using a post method. It works fine in my Android device, but fails in both broswer and Ripple emulator. Here is the code:

```
function queryImageByData(dataURL) {

    var imgType = dataURL.substring(5, dataURL.indexOf(";"));
    var imgExt = imgType.split("/")[1];
    var imgData = atob(dataURL.substring(dataURL.indexOf(",") + 1));

    var filenameTimestamp = (new Date().getTime());

    var separator = "----------12345-multipart-boundary-" + filenameTimestamp;
    var formData = "--" + separator + "\r\n" +
    "Content-Disposition: file; name=\"file\"; filename=\"snapshot_" + filenameTimestamp + "." + imgExt + "\"\r\n" +
    "Content-Type: " + imgType + "\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64" + "\r\n\r\n" + imgData + "\r\n--" + separator + "\r\n";


    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


    xhr.sendAsBinary = function (data) {
        var arrb = new ArrayBuffer(data.length);
        var ui8a = new Uint8Array(arrb, 0);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            ui8a[i] = (data.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff);
        }

        var blob = new Blob([arrb]);
        this.send(blob);
    };


    xhr.open("POST", "https:/my_endpoint_here", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                parseResult(xhr.responseText);
            }
            else {
                onFailedResponse(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + separator);
    xhr.sendAsBinary(formData);
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: MultipartParser.end(): stream ended unexpectedly: state = HEADER_FIELD_START
    at MultipartParser.end
```

**EDIT:**

I have a problem also with a get method. It fails on Ripple/Browser but runs OK on the device. here is some sample code:

```
var url = document.getElementById("urlInput").value;

    var query = "my_url_here";     
    var jqxhr = $.ajax(query)
  .done(function (data) {
      alert("success" + data);
  })
  .fail(function (data) {
      alert("error" + data);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the core issue, which cross domain calls.
The browsers do not allow it, and apperently so does Ripple emulator,
but mobile devices do allow it.
Now I just need to figure out how to make it work using [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).